# Why i cannot save the test plan in jmeter?

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, stress-testing

regarding test plan not saving .
I right clicked at test plan->choose save selection as ..->any window/popup box should open but getting no response..
I am using "jdk-16.0.1_windows-x64_bin".and
"apache-jmeter-5.4.1"
[As indicated in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PylNz.png)i clicked but get nothing

Answer (score 33):

Just simply change to the e.g. System look and view instead of Dark.
[image]

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks you very much :)

Comment: Can't believe it actually works. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you pay attention to upper right corner of your JMeter GUI you will see that there are 32 errors, most probably one of them can explain what's going on if you look into [jmeter.log file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/)

Most probably you're suffering from [JMeter Bug 65300](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65300) so the options are in:

1. Downgrade to [Java 8](https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/8-MR3)
2. Try out [Nightly Build of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html)
3. Try switching to another [Look and Feel](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#laf_config)

Comment: Dmitri is correct, the darklaf look-and-feel of apache-jmeter-5.4.1 suffers from Bug 65300.

Changing the look and feel to Metal and restarting JMeter 5.4.1 worked for me. The save dialog appears allowing you to save the Test plan

Comment: yes Metal theme worked for me too. Thank you Dmitri and Philip

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, number three did the trick for me. Funny though that it was the default look that was faulty :D